# Kubernetes job with ephemeral ingress in Helm test

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm rolling a custom Helm chart for [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) and I'm trying to leverage Helm test to test external-dns is installed correctly and working.

What I need in the test is an ingress that uses external-dns to create a record and a k8s job/pod that hits that ingress via its dns record- waiting X number of mins to time out.

I can create a pod/job easily that will be torn down when it's finished, but how do I do that with an ingress? After the test completes I want the ingress to be deleted.

Comment: You can use Jobs to finish and deleted pods if they're completed - see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/ However to to automatically deleted Ingress connected with pods you will have to created script with handler. There is no such mechanism in Kubernetes.

Comment: I cant find any examples of how to use a helm hook to delete an ingress in a helm test

Comment: As I have mentioned you would have to write your own handler/script.